# Nginx requests came without get or post type

Tags: php, nginx, request

I have nginx + php-fpm server and i run website on port 6001.
My target is get terminal requests and parse them and return answer.

Terminal sends requests like that (log request)

```
192.168.1.20 - - [10/Oct/2019:18:00:22 +0600] "9900302.00" 400 173 "-" "-"
```

i need to get that string

```
9900302.00" 400 173
```

and i dont know how.

my nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 6001;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/sip2-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/sip2-error.log;
    root /var/www/sip2/public_html;

    location / {
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you looking for assistance writing PHP to retrieve the body of the request are you looking for server configuration help?

Comment: standalone terminal send TCP request, i want to parse that request. But i dont know how